# Record audio on iPhone not saving

Tags: ios, cordova

I have done a lot of looking, and it seems like the code is correct. I dont have any clue where to go from here. it just does not record anything

```
if(device.platform == "iPhone")
{
myFileRecord = "myrecording.wav";myMime="audio/x-wav";

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function onDeviceReady() {
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS1, function fail1(){});
}, false);

var gotFS1 = function (fileSystem) {
fileSystem.root.getFile("myrecording.wav",
    { create: true, exclusive: false }, //create if it does not exist
    function success(entry) {
        var src = entry.toURI();
        console.log(src); //logs blank.wav's path starting with file://
    },
    function fail1() {}
);
};

}
recordAudio();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can't use '==' to check a string.

Try:

```
if ([device.platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
```

Furthermore, you may want to check out http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models and look at the column "Identifier".  These are likely what 'device.platform' is going to be set to.